# ¿Cómo mostrar correctamente un texto por pantalla en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar, ando haciendo ejercicios, este código se supone que tiene errores pero es que no veo los errores por ningún sitio.

```
11. System.out.println("El valor de x es ", x, " y el valor de y es ", y);
12. System.out.println("El resultado de x + y es " + (x + y));
13. System.out.println("El resultado de x - y es " + (x - y));
14. System.out.printf("\n%s%s\n","División entera:","x / y = ",(x/y));
15. System.out.println("Resto de la división entera: x % y = " + (x % y));
16. System.out.printf("El valor de f1 es %f y el de f2 es %f\n",f1,f2);
17. System.out.println("El resultado de f1 / f2 es " + (f1 / f2))
```

A ver, corrijo el código señalando los errores y me comentáis:

```
11. System.out.println("El valor de x es x y el valor de y es y");
12. System.out.println("El resultado de x + y es " + (x + y));
13. System.out.println("El resultado de x - y es " + (x - y));
14. System.out.printf("\n%s%s\n","División entera:","x / y = ",(x/y));
15. System.out.println("Resto de la división entera: x % y = " + (x % y));
16. System.out.printf("El valor de f1 es %f y el de f2 es %f\n",f1,f2);
17. System.out.println("El resultado de f1 / f2 es " + (f1 / f2))
```

A ver, no entiendo este código la verdad. Pongo mis dudas:

· Entiendo que en el contenido de lo que imprimes en pantalla con System.out.println no puedes poner comillas dentro porque ya tienes todo entre comillas, ¿no?

· En las siguientes líneas de código cuando te pone comillas que te dice: "el resultado de x + y es " la verdad es que no entiendo que significan esas comillas.

· En la línea 14 no comprendo el código `(14. System.out.printf("\n%s%s\n","División entera:","x / y = ",(x/y));)`. Sé que printf se utiliza para dar formato en Java. Entonces: me mete dos saltos de línea y entre medias un s% que no sé para qué sirve, luego me pone división entera que entiendo que es texto que aparece en pantalla y luego x/y me lo repite dos veces.

· El resto de líneas tampoco comprendo absolutamente nada, quiero decir... ¿alguien me puede explicar qué reglas hay para poner comillas, para qué sirven estos operadores, qué reglas de sintaxis tienen etc.?

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Creo que se podria armar una respuesta, pero lo mas importante es que leas como funciona la funcion printf y println. No se cual es tu confusion con las comillas, todo texto (string, cadena) va entre comillas. asi es como se declaran. Para empezar, lee sobre cadenas y como funcionan esas funciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Definiciones

**[`System.out.println(String x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String))** siempre aceptará un solo parámetro, ya sea el tipo de dato boolean, char, char[], double, float, int, long, Objeto o String.

**[`printf(String format, Object... args`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)** tendrá que tener como primer parámetro el texto y formato que van a tener los parámetros y después tantos argumentos como queramos y hayamos definido en el formato del texto, separados por comas.

En caso de que hubiera más parámetros que especificadores de formato estos parámetros se ignorarán.

### Las comillas y System.out.println()

Las comillas se pueden utilizar dentro de la función `System.out.println()`, puesto que vas a imprimir un texto por pantalla y todo lo que esté contenido dentro de comillas será considerado como texto.

En caso de que quieras concatenar un texto con el resultado de una variable lo tendrás que hacer mediante el símbolo `+` y no con comas (como en tu ejemplo 11).

Por ejemplo, imaginando que tenemos `x=5`:

```
System.out.println("Esto es el resultado de la variable x: " + x);
```

Imprimiría lo siguiente:

```
Esto es el resultado de la variable x: 5
```

Es decir, no es que repitas dos veces la x, si no que lo que está dentro de las comillas lo evalúa "tal y como es", es decir, no interpreta su valor. En cambio, cuando utilizamos la variable `x` fuera de las comillas nos mostrará el valor correspondiente de esa variable.

Lo mismo ocurre en tus ejemplos 12, 13, 15 y 17, solo que en estos casos muestra por pantalla el resultado de operaciones en vez de únicamente el resultado de una variable.

**NOTA:** Tendrás que tener cuidado en caso de que quieras mostrar un String en el que se muestren comillas, ya que estas son caracteres especiales y tendrás que escaparlas. Para escapar un carácter especial y que se muestre "tal y como es" en un String, deberás de usar la barra invertida `\` justo antes del carácter especial.

Un ejemplo sería:

```
System.out.println("Esto es un ejemplo en el que el resultado contendrá \"comillas\"");
```

Y el resultado sería:

```
Esto es un ejemplo en el que el resultado contendrá "comillas"
```

### printf

Sirve para imprimir por pantalla un texto con cierto formato.

Tiene algunos "formateadores" para las variables de salida. Los que veo que usas son:

```
%s --> Cogerá el siguiente argumento y lo imprimirá como string
%f --> Cogerá el siguiente parámetro y lo imprimirá como float
```

Es decir, cogiendo tu ejemplo 16:

```
System.out.printf("El valor de f1 es %f y el de f2 es %f\n",f1,f2);
```

Lo que va a hacer es en el primer `%f` va a imprimir el valor de `f1` como float y en el segundo `%f` va a imprimir `f2` como float.

En este caso, cuando imprimas el resultado no te mostrará el contenido de las comillas "tal y como es" como pasaba con `System.out.println` si no que te sustituirá cada uno de los `%f` por el resultado de las variables que pasas como parámetros en orden de situación (el primer `%f` con el primer parámetro, el segundo `%f` con el segundo parámetro y asi sucesivamente...)